# ASP.NET Response.Redirect to open a new browser window?

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are using ASP.NET Webforms (not MVC).

My question is this: 
Is it possible to open a new browser window using a postback and then some variety of Response.Redirect?

Comment: Have you tried any thing ?

Comment: Response.Redirect cannot open a browser as Response.Redirect is Server side command, and browser doesn't exists on server. You need to throw a javascript code to open a new window as @JLC007 suggest in it's answer.

Answer (score 7):

I have not come across instances where Response.Redirect can navigate opening a new window.

Here are a way of doing it not using Response.Redirect which you can try:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "New_Window", "window.open( 'http://www.website.com', null, 'height=800,width=1280,status=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,location=no' );", true);
```

Comment: You can add `'_blank'` in place of the `null` but I tested it and both give the same result. It opens a new window.

Comment: Note that browsers may treat scripts that run on page load in this manner as being page-initiated, rather than user-initiated.  Such links may be blocked by popup-blockers.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer? No.

Long answer:

ASP.NET is a server side framework,  whereas the concept of browser windows is a client side one. `Response.Redirect` just ends up sending a `Location: [whatever the new url is]` header as part of the output stream. It just happens that pretty much all browsers handle that header by loading up the url that's in that header.

The most pain-free way would be using javascript on the postback to open the new window, as outlined in [JLC007's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18094918/115049) answer. Another possible option is using the [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-target) attribute on the rendered form.

Comment: I suppose "shortly" is relative, but when is the longer answer coming?

Comment: Just now. Got sidetracked.

Comment: I would probably use another source when linking to target, namely [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-target). Even though w3schools often has valid information, there's the question of quality (http://www.w3fools.com/).

Comment: Thx for the tip, didn't realize they weren't W3C affiliated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "openWindow", 
     "window.open( 'http://www.website.com', target="_blank", 
     'height=800,width=1280,status=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,location=no' );",
       true);
```

Comment: And this is different from the answer by JLC007, how?

Comment: target is different and it's use to open a new window